# my varnish always miss

Tags: magento2, varnish

My varnish always miss,but if i refresh many time in one second,it will return hit.

This is my default.vcl

```
# VCL version 5.0 is not supported so it should be 4.0 even though actually used Varnish version is 6
vcl 4.0;

import std;
# The minimal Varnish version is 6.0
# For SSL offloading, pass the following header in your proxy server or load balancer: 'X-Forwarded-Proto: https'

backend default {
    .host = "localhost";
    .port = "8080";
    .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
    .probe = {
        .url = "/health_check.php";
        .timeout = 2s;
        .interval = 5s;
        .window = 10;
        .threshold = 5;
   }
}

acl purge {
    "localhost";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.restarts > 0) {
        set req.hash_always_miss = true;
    }
    if (req.http.User-Agent ~ "iP(?:hone|ad|od)|BlackBerry|Palm|Googlebot-Mobile|Mobile|mobile|mobi|Windows Mobile|Safari Mobile|Android|Opera (?:Mini|Mobi)") {
         set req.http.X-Device = "mobile";
    } else {
         set req.http.X-Device = "other";
    }
    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
        if (client.ip !~ purge) {
            return (synth(405, "Method not allowed"));
        }
        # To use the X-Pool header for purging varnish during automated deployments, make sure the X-Pool header
        # has been added to the response in your backend server config. This is used, for example, by the
        # capistrano-magento2 gem for purging old content from varnish during it's deploy routine.
        if (!req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern && !req.http.X-Pool) {
            return (synth(400, "X-Magento-Tags-Pattern or X-Pool header required"));
        }
        if (req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern) {
          ban("obj.http.X-Magento-Tags ~ " + req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern);
        }
        if (req.http.X-Pool) {
          ban("obj.http.X-Pool ~ " + req.http.X-Pool);
        }
        return (synth(200, "Purged"));
    }

    if (req.method != "GET" &&
        req.method != "HEAD" &&
        req.method != "PUT" &&
        req.method != "POST" &&
        req.method != "TRACE" &&
        req.method != "OPTIONS" &&
        req.method != "DELETE") {
          /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
          return (pipe);
    }

    # We only deal with GET and HEAD by default
    if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Bypass shopping cart and checkout
    if (req.url ~ "/checkout" || req.url ~ "/catalogsearch") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Bypass health check requests
    if (req.url ~ "/health_check.php") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Set initial grace period usage status
    set req.http.grace = "none";

    # normalize url in case of leading HTTP scheme and domain
    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "^http[s]?://", "");

    # collect all cookies
    std.collect(req.http.Cookie);

    # Compression filter. See https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/FAQ/Compression
    if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
        if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg|swf|flv)$") {
            # No point in compressing these
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate" && req.http.user-agent !~ "MSIE") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
        } else {
            # unknown algorithm
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        }
    }

    # Remove all marketing get parameters to minimize the cache objects
    if (req.url ~ "(\?|&)(gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl|zanpid|origin|fbclid|mc_[a-z]+|utm_[a-z]+|_bta_[a-z]+)=") {
        set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "(gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl|zanpid|origin|fbclid|mc_[a-z]+|utm_[a-z]+|_bta_[a-z]+)=[-_A-z0-9+()%.]+&?", "");
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "[?|&]+$", "");
    }

    # Static files caching
    if (req.url ~ "^/(pub/)?(media|static)/") {
        # Static files should not be cached by default
        return (pass);

        # But if you use a few locales and don't use CDN you can enable caching static files by commenting previous line (#return (pass);) and uncommenting next 3 lines
        #unset req.http.Https;
        #unset req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto;
    }

    # Authenticated GraphQL requests should not be cached by default
    if (req.url ~ "/graphql" && req.http.Authorization ~ "^Bearer") {
        return (pass);
    }

    return (hash);
}

sub vcl_hash {
    if (req.http.cookie ~ "X-Magento-Vary=") {
        hash_data(regsub(req.http.cookie, "^.*?X-Magento-Vary=([^;]+);*.*$", "\1"));
    }
    if (req.http.X-Device) {
        hash_data(req.http.X-Device);
    }
    # To make sure http users don't see ssl warning
    if (req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto) {
        hash_data(req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto);
    }


    if (req.url ~ "/graphql") {
        call process_graphql_headers;
    }
}

sub process_graphql_headers {
    if (req.http.Store) {
        hash_data(req.http.Store);
    }
    if (req.http.Content-Currency) {
        hash_data(req.http.Content-Currency);
    }
}

sub vcl_backend_response {

    set beresp.grace = 3d;

    if (beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_esi = true;
    }

    if (bereq.url ~ "\.js$" || beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_gzip = true;
    }

    if (beresp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        set beresp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Control = beresp.http.Cache-Control;
    }

    # cache only successfully responses and 404s
    if (beresp.status != 200 && beresp.status != 404) {
        set beresp.ttl = 0s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        return (deliver);
    } elsif (beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "private") {
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        set beresp.ttl = 86400s;
        return (deliver);
    }

    # validate if we need to cache it and prevent from setting cookie
    if (beresp.ttl > 0s && (bereq.method == "GET" || bereq.method == "HEAD")) {
        unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    }

   # If page is not cacheable then bypass varnish for 2 minutes as Hit-For-Pass
   if (beresp.ttl <= 0s ||
       beresp.http.Surrogate-control ~ "no-store" ||
       (!beresp.http.Surrogate-Control &&
       beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache|no-store") ||
       beresp.http.Vary == "*") {
        # Mark as Hit-For-Pass for the next 2 minutes
        set beresp.ttl = 120s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
    }

    return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    if (resp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        if (resp.http.x-varnish ~ " ") {
            set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "HIT";
            set resp.http.Grace = req.http.grace;
        } else {
            set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "MISS";
        }
    } else {
        unset resp.http.Age;
    }
    set resp.http.X-Varnish-Device = req.http.X-Device;
    # Not letting browser to cache non-static files.
    if (resp.http.Cache-Control !~ "private" && req.url !~ "^/(pub/)?(media|static)/") {
        set resp.http.Pragma = "no-cache";
        set resp.http.Expires = "-1";
        set resp.http.Cache-Control = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0";
    }

    unset resp.http.X-Magento-Debug;
    unset resp.http.X-Magento-Tags;
    unset resp.http.X-Powered-By;
    unset resp.http.Server;
    unset resp.http.X-Varnish;
    unset resp.http.Via;
    unset resp.http.Link;
}

sub vcl_hit {
    if (obj.ttl >= 0s) {
        # Hit within TTL period
        return (deliver);
    }
    }
    if (std.healthy(req.backend_hint)) {
        if (obj.ttl + 300s > 0s) {
            # Hit after TTL expiration, but within grace period
            set req.http.grace = "normal (healthy server)";
            return (deliver);
        } else {
            # Hit after TTL and grace expiration
            return (restart);
        }
    } else {
        # server is not healthy, retrieve from cache
        set req.http.grace = "unlimited (unhealthy server)";
        return (deliver);
    }
}
```

I check all the `cacheable=false` block,it haven't be require all page,but my website all the page always miss

my varnishlog

```
*   << Request  >> 2196003   
-   Begin          req 2196002 rxreq
-   Timestamp      Start: 1629880451.930923 0.000000 0.000000
-   Timestamp      Req: 1629880451.930923 0.000000 0.000000
-   VCL_use        boot
-   ReqStart       127.0.0.1 48442 a0
-   ReqMethod      GET
-   ReqURL         /
-   ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.1
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
-   ReqHeader      Host: mywebsite.com
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Host: mywebsite.com
-   ReqHeader      X-Real-IP: mywebsiteip
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: mywebsiteip
-   ReqHeader      Ssl-Offloaded: 1
-   ReqHeader      X-Scheme: https
-   ReqHeader      X-Secure: on
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Proto: https
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Port: 443
-   ReqHeader      Connection: close
-   ReqHeader      Cache-Control: max-age=0
-   ReqHeader      sec-ch-ua: " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"
-   ReqHeader      sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
-   ReqHeader      Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
-   ReqHeader      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36
-   ReqHeader      Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Fetch-Site: none
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Language: en,zh-CN;q=0.9,zh;q=0.8
-   ReqHeader      Cookie: _gcl_au=1.1.2020958957.1625536238; _pin_unauth=dWlkPU0yWmlabVV4WVdFdE5tVTBNaTAwTjJGaExXSTVOREF0Tm1JMU0yRXpZVFUzTVRabQ; gr_user_id=dd158320-4dea-4d91-a9f2-00d4a6e062d5; _fbp=fb.1.1626771346305.614438770; sensorsdata2015jssdkcross=%7B%22distinct_id
-   ReqUnset       X-Forwarded-For: mywebsiteip
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: mywebsiteip, 127.0.0.1
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   ReqHeader      X-Device: other
-   ReqHeader      grace: none
-   ReqURL         /
-   ReqUnset       Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   VCL_return     hash
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   VCL_call       MISS
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   Link           bereq 2196004 fetch
-   Timestamp      Fetch: 1629880454.676736 2.745813 2.745813
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
-   RespStatus     200
-   RespReason     OK
-   RespHeader     Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
-   RespHeader     Date: Wed, 25 Aug 2021 08:34:14 GMT
-   RespHeader     Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
-   RespHeader     Vary: Accept-Encoding
-   RespHeader     Pragma: cache
-   RespHeader     Cache-Control: max-age=86400, public, s-maxage=86400
-   RespHeader     Expires: Thu, 26 Aug 2021 08:34:12 GMT
-   RespHeader     X-Magento-Tags: cat_c,cat_c_3,cat_c_103,cat_c_108,cat_c_106,cat_c_105,cat_c_176,store,cms_b,cms_b_activity-header,cms_b_small-business-big-mission,cms_b_top-picks-block,cat_p_11970,cat_p,cat_p_11733,cat_p_11752,cat_p_12764,cat_p_11327,cat_p_11401,cat_p_1
-   RespHeader     X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
-   RespHeader     X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
-   RespHeader     X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
-   RespHeader     Content-Encoding: gzip
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 2196003
-   RespHeader     Age: 0
-   RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.2)
-   VCL_call       DELIVER
-   RespUnset      Age: 0
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish-Device: other
-   RespUnset      Pragma: cache
-   RespHeader     Pragma: no-cache
-   RespUnset      Expires: Thu, 26 Aug 2021 08:34:12 GMT
-   RespHeader     Expires: -1
-   RespUnset      Cache-Control: max-age=86400, public, s-maxage=86400
-   RespHeader     Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
-   RespUnset      X-Magento-Tags: cat_c,cat_c_3,cat_c_103,cat_c_108,cat_c_106,cat_c_105,cat_c_176,store,cms_b,cms_b_activity-header,cms_b_small-business-big-mission,cms_b_top-picks-block,cat_p_11970,cat_p,cat_p_11733,cat_p_11752,cat_p_12764,cat_p_11327,cat_p_11401,cat_p_1
-   RespUnset      Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
-   RespUnset      X-Varnish: 2196003
-   RespUnset      Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.2)
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Timestamp      Process: 1629880454.676765 2.745842 0.000030
-   Filters        
-   RespHeader     Accept-Ranges: bytes
-   RespHeader     Content-Length: 34997
-   RespHeader     Connection: close
-   Timestamp      Resp: 1629880454.676821 2.745898 0.000056
-   ReqAcct        3385 0 3385 421 34997 35418
-   End            
**  << BeReq    >> 2196004   
--  Begin          bereq 2196003 fetch
--  VCL_use        boot
--  Timestamp      Start: 1629880451.931008 0.000000 0.000000
--  BereqMethod    GET
--  BereqURL       /
--  BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1
--  BereqHeader    Host: mywebsite.com
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Host: mywebsite.com
--  BereqHeader    X-Real-IP: mywebsiteip
--  BereqHeader    Ssl-Offloaded: 1
--  BereqHeader    X-Scheme: https
--  BereqHeader    X-Secure: on
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Proto: https
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Port: 443
--  BereqHeader    sec-ch-ua: " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"
--  BereqHeader    sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
--  BereqHeader    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
--  BereqHeader    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36
--  BereqHeader    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
--  BereqHeader    Sec-Fetch-Site: none
--  BereqHeader    Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
--  BereqHeader    Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
--  BereqHeader    Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
--  BereqHeader    Accept-Language: en,zh-CN;q=0.9,zh;q=0.8
--  BereqHeader    Cookie: _gcl_au=1.1.2020958957.1625536238; _pin_unauth=dWlkPU0yWmlabVV4WVdFdE5tVTBNaTAwTjJGaExXSTVOREF0Tm1JMU0yRXpZVFUzTVRabQ; gr_user_id=dd158320-4dea-4d91-a9f2-00d4a6e062d5; _fbp=fb.1.1626771346305.614438770; sensorsdata2015jssdkcross=%7B%22distinct_id
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: mywebsiteip, 127.0.0.1
--  BereqHeader    X-Device: other
--  BereqHeader    grace: none
--  BereqHeader    Accept-Encoding: gzip
--  BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 2196004
--  VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
--  VCL_return     fetch
--  BackendOpen    27 default 127.0.0.1 8080 127.0.0.1 51474
--  BackendStart   127.0.0.1 8080
--  Timestamp      Bereq: 1629880451.931079 0.000071 0.000071
--  Timestamp      Beresp: 1629880454.664853 2.733845 2.733773
--  BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
--  BerespStatus   200
--  BerespReason   OK
--  BerespHeader   Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
--  BerespHeader   Date: Wed, 25 Aug 2021 08:34:14 GMT
--  BerespHeader   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
--  BerespHeader   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
--  BerespHeader   Connection: keep-alive
--  BerespHeader   Vary: Accept-Encoding
--  BerespHeader   Set-Cookie: form_key=Plg9UyxhkRDmTsyB; expires=Wed, 25-Aug-2021 09:34:12 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=mywebsite.com; secure; SameSite=Lax
--  BerespHeader   Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=vhsehatfhkvoiorjiqbfum83m5; expires=Wed, 25-Aug-2021 09:34:12 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=mywebsite.com; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
--  BerespHeader   Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=vhsehatfhkvoiorjiqbfum83m5; expires=Wed, 25-Aug-2021 09:34:12 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=mywebsite.com; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
--  BerespHeader   Set-Cookie: X-Magento-Vary=11f92daa01a00c59c29f7edfbcc955e7aabcebe3; expires=Wed, 25-Aug-2021 09:34:14 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
--  BerespHeader   Pragma: cache
--  BerespHeader   Cache-Control: max-age=86400, public, s-maxage=86400
--  BerespHeader   Expires: Thu, 26 Aug 2021 08:34:12 GMT
--  BerespHeader   X-Magento-Tags: cat_c,cat_c_3,cat_c_103,cat_c_108,cat_c_106,cat_c_105,cat_c_176,store,cms_b,cms_b_activity-header,cms_b_small-business-big-mission,cms_b_top-picks-block,cat_p_11970,cat_p,cat_p_11733,cat_p_11752,cat_p_12764,cat_p_11327,cat_p_11401,cat_p_1
--  BerespHeader   X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
--  BerespHeader   X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
--  BerespHeader   X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
--  BerespHeader   Content-Encoding: gzip
--  TTL            RFC 86400 10 0 1629880455 1629880455 1629880454 1629966852 86400 cacheable
--  VCL_call       BACKEND_RESPONSE
--  TTL            VCL 86400 259200 0 1629880455 cacheable
--  BerespUnset    Set-Cookie: form_key=Plg9UyxhkRDmTsyB; expires=Wed, 25-Aug-2021 09:34:12 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=mywebsite.com; secure; SameSite=Lax
--  BerespUnset    Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=vhsehatfhkvoiorjiqbfum83m5; expires=Wed, 25-Aug-2021 09:34:12 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=mywebsite.com; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
--  BerespUnset    Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=vhsehatfhkvoiorjiqbfum83m5; expires=Wed, 25-Aug-2021 09:34:12 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=mywebsite.com; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
--  BerespUnset    Set-Cookie: X-Magento-Vary=11f92daa01a00c59c29f7edfbcc955e7aabcebe3; expires=Wed, 25-Aug-2021 09:34:14 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
--  VCL_return     deliver
--  Filters        gunzip esi_gzip
--  BerespUnset    Content-Encoding: gzip
--  BerespHeader   Content-Encoding: gzip
--  Storage        malloc s0
--  Fetch_Body     2 chunked -
--  Gzip           G F E 310259 34997 80 279896 279906
--  Gzip           U F - 34986 310259 80 201463 279819
--  BackendReuse   27 default
--  Timestamp      BerespBody: 1629880454.676729 2.745721 0.011876
--  Length         34997
--  BereqAcct      3388 0 3388 1636 0 1636
--  End
```

my `nginx.conf`

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/a.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/a.key;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE:ECDH:AES:HIGH:!NULL:!aNULL:!MD5:!ADH:!RC4;

    server_name mywebsite.com;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
  #add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000" always;
  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl_stapling_verify on;
  keepalive_timeout 300s;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6081;
    proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding  $http_accept_encoding;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Ssl-Offloaded "1";
    proxy_set_header X-Scheme https;
    proxy_set_header X-Secure on;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_read_timeout 7200s;
    proxy_send_timeout 7200s;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume you're trying to get a cache hit from the homepage.

We can use `varnishlog` to check the logs and see what's going on.

Please provide the output of the following command when you're testing the homepage:

```
varnishlog -g request -q "ReqUrl eq '/'"
```

The logs will give us the necessary insight into what happens behind the scenes and why the page results in a cache miss.

### Update: `Set-Cookie` headers are causing `Hit-For-Miss`

After seeing the backend side of the Varnish logs, I can conclude that the numerous `Set-Cookie` headers in the HTTP response are responsible for the fact that the page is not stored in the cache.

This is not a bug, this is not exceptional behavior, this is expected and normal: a `Set-Cookie` header implies a state change and shouldn't be cached.

Varnish will ensure that HTTP responses containing a `Set-Cookie` header will end up in the `Hit-For-Miss` cache. This is a cache that keeps track of objects that shouldn't be cached.

The standard TTL for `Hit-For-Miss` is 2 minutes. This means that for the next 2 minutes requests for this page will not end up on Varnish's internal waiting list, because these requests can never be satisfied by a so-called *request coalescing*.

By storing the object in the `Hit-For-Miss` cache, Varnish allows subsequent requests to immediately bypass the waiting list and connect directly to the origin server. If that wouldn't be the case, requests would get stuck on the waiting list and serial processing of this list would cause significant delay.

As mentioned, the TTL for `Hit-For-Miss` is 2 minutes, but objects can leave the `Hit-For-Miss` cache when the next response is cacheable.

> The solution is to not use `Set-Cookie` headers on the homepage and rethink your cookie strategy. Some of these cookies shouldn't be set on the homepage and should appear when a user takes specific actions that require the state change a `Set-Cookie` header is designed for.

### Update 2: how to handle cookies with Varnish & Magento

I potential cookie strategy is to not set cookies unless the user actually logs in. The moment the login form is submitted, Magento can set the `Set-Cookie` response header that includes the cookies that need to be set.

Varnish will see the `Set-Cookie` header and will drop the response in the `Hit-For-Miss` cache for 2 minutes.

The next request for this resource shouldn't perform a `Set-Cookie`, because the cookie was already sent and received via the `Cookie` request header. The means that the resource can be removed from `Hit-For-Miss` and can potentially become cacheable.

However, on the one hand, objects can be stored in the cache if they are deemed cacheable. On the other hand, requests that are considered uncacheable will not be served from the cache, even though the response might be stored in the cache.

The decision to lookup an object in the cache will depend on the URL. For checkout, the cache will be bypassed. For many other pages, Varnish will try to serve them from the cache.

An extra factor is the `X-Magento-Vary` cookie that may have been set. The value of this cookie is used to serve cache variations.

Whereas Varnish is configured to serve as much from the cache as possible (except for `/checkout`), it's up to Magento to use `Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store headers to prevent pages from being cached unnecessarily.

> Long story short: only perform a `Set-Cookie` when a user takes action. For example, when the user logs in. Don't use `Set-Cookie` headers preemptively for *what if* scenarios. The response will only set a cookie once and that response will be uncacheable.

Comment: I added the log.

Comment: I found that when my request through curl with `--cookie`,varnish is working normal,but it always miss when I use browser.My browser request always have different `x-magento-vary` param,every request are different.

Comment: @kair It's probably going to be related to to the `x-magento-vary` cookie, however I would like to see the backend side of your Varnish logs. Did you use the `-c` option to only include client-side requests? I'm particularly interested in how Varnish behaves when it receives the response from the backend. Please updated your VSL output and include the full log for the request.

Comment: I use nginx to proxy the request to varnish,so add the `-c` will be the same output.I add the nginx config?

Comment: @kair I just need `varnishlog -g request -q "ReqUrl eq '/'"` without the `-c` flag, because I want to see the full `varnishlog` output, not just the client-side info that is provided by the `-c` flag. I want to see tags like `BerespHeader`, `TTL` and many other backend-related tags.

Comment: I updated the log

Comment: I read your solution,but I have not idea to solve it.I can't unset the cookie because my customer maybe always login in.This problem not only in my home page but also in product detail page and so on.

Comment: @kair: added another update, I hope that clarifies the situation.